# Lambda Cloudwatch log entry has START event but nothing else afterward. Lambda mysteriously disappears

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-cloudwatch

We have four examples where we have a Lambda log entry for the START event and then nothing, not even a REPORT. How can I find out what caused these Lambdas to mysteriously stop logging?

Below is an an example. I searched for the logs for the 16 minutes after the START message appears; nothing except the START event shows. I had a quick look at the logStream and did not see anything obvious there either.

**CloudWatch Logs Insights**
region: us-west-2
log-group-names: /aws/lambda/xxx-LambdaFunction-yyy
start-time: 2021-02-05T00:41:56.000Z
end-time: 2021-02-05T00:58:00.000Z
query-string:

```
fields @timestamp, @message, @logStream
| sort @timestamp desc
| filter @requestId = 'd43571cf-6185-4f4a-82cc-6212867cf4b5'
```

```
2021-02-05 00:41:56.916 | START RequestId: d43571cf-6185-4f4a-82cc-6212867cf4b5 Version: 137
```

I've looked at the logStream that contains this event did not see anything obvious.

Comment: Try locating them in the specific log stream so that you can have some context information.

Comment: @jellycsc Like I said in my question, I located the events in the logStream. There's nothing unusual.

Comment: Did you find what was the problem?